# C# COM Interop Creating New Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, com-interop, winforms-interop

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in a C# winform but I can't figure out how to create a new Excel workbook.  I have tried everything in the documentation but I get nothing but errors.  Workbook wb = new Workbook() compiles just fine but throws an incomprehensible runtime error.

Comment: What is the "incomprehensible runtime error"?  It might be comprehensible to someone here...

Comment: Here's the error message: `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting the same error as you would get if you tried to instantiate a Workbook in Excel VBA using

```
Dim w As Workbook
Set w = New Workbook
```

Try instantiating the `Application` object, then call the `Application.Workbooks.Add` method.  It takes an optional parameter, which is the name of a template.

Comment: Thanks.  I was using ExcelLibrary but I got frustrated due to the complete lack of documentation.  I just switched over to COM Interop and it's all new.

Comment: You will find that COM Interop is not exactly well documented either :-)  At least, the answers to many questions are well-buried.

Comment: With Office, it's sometimes easier to get it working using VBA first, then convert to .NET using COM Interop.